# Clear the console in javascript without any message

Tags: javascript, console.log

I need to print a lot of data to the console every frame, but I only want to see the current frame‘s data. I know that I can clear the console with `console.clear()` But this leaves a message (usually `console was cleared`), and it looks kind of weird every time that it updates, because there is nothing for a second, and then it the data for the frame comes in, and it looks like an old tv. Is there anyway to write over your last console log with new data (getting rid of the old tv look) , or at least get rid of message that comes with `console.clear()`?

**Edit:**
This is a browser web page, not a node server (I wasn't clear enough, sorry).

Comment: Is this for a node application where you're logging to a terminal, or is it in a browser?

Comment: the only way than is to artificial clean it by logging some \n or empty console.log, but accordin to mozzila docs theres is no other way to really clean the console programatically

Comment: ctrl + L just clear the terminal screen.

Comment: @Jacob, browser, not node.

Comment: If this is just for your purposes, you can always overwrite `console` with your own function that just writes it to a dynamic div on the screen via a bookmarklet.